# How do summations/integrals like Fourier, Laplace, z-transforms preserve all the information about the original signal?

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, integral-transforms, z-transform

In normal summations, like 2+3=5, the information about the original numbers is lost. But in infinite summations like integral transforms, no information is lost and the function can still be recovered. What about integral transforms makes this possible? Give a less formal explanation (I mean, just avoid complex terminology. Use high school familiar terms)

Comment: To use your analogy, yes, $2+3 = 5$ alone causes a loss of information, but if you add a second equation, say $2-3 =-1$, then you've recovered the lost information. The equation $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$ is of the form $Ax = b$, where $A$ is invertible. Similarly, on certain domains of functions, the Fourier and other transforms are invertible operations. For example, the Fourier transform is an invertible mapping from $L^2$ to itself.

Comment: @Bungo That's really good. I want to know how they are invertible and other made-up transforms (like $\int_0^1 f(x)^bdx$) are not. Also, summations can be invertible because they form systems of linear equations, like in your example. But how can integrals be invertible? Won't there be a system of infinite equations or something?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, with one major issue: it's too broad. Could you specify one particular transformation that you'd like explained? If the explanation doesn't apply to other transformations, then ask another question.

Comment: It actually takes quite a lot of work to show that the Fourier transform is invertible on certain spaces. If I recall correctly, you start by showing that it's an invertible mapping from the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) to itself, and then use the fact that the Schwartz functions are dense in $L^2$ to prove that there is a unique continuous extension of the Fourier transform to $L^2$. Then you show that this extension agrees with the usual Fourier transform defined via integration for functions that are also in $L^1$.

Comment: It's a lot easier to prove invertibility in the [discrete case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). In that case, the Fourier transform is simply a change of basis on $\mathbb R^n$ (or $\mathbb C^n$), where $n$ is the length of the input and output vectors. Consequently, you can represent the Fourier transform as a particular invertible matrix.

Comment: @Bungo there isn't anything common in invertible transforms which makes them invertible? Invertibility has to be proven for each transform separately?

Comment: The transforms you listed are related to each other in some cases, for example, the Fourier transform on the space of sequences (so-called [discrete-time Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform)) is the z-transform evaluated on the unit circle in the complex plane. So in some cases you may be able to deduce invertibility of one of the transforms from invertibility of another.

Answer (score 1):

Summations (or integrals) in discrete and continuous Fourier transforms merely takes points in one infinite dimensional space (e.g., continuous functions of a real variable) and express them as a different continuous function.  No information is lost (in typical cases) because the basis set spans the space.